# NoSuchMethodError: The getter was called on null

Tags: flutter, localization

```
        `
    class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ChangeNotifierProvider( //Comes from provider class
            create: (context) => LocaleProvider(),
            builder: (context, child) {
              final provider = Provider.of<LocaleProvider>(context);
              return MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                title: 'Forts In Maharashtra',
                locale: provider.locale,
                supportedLocales: L10n.all,
                localizationsDelegates: [
                  AppLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
                  GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
                ],
                home: MyApp(),
              );
            });
      }
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      //static const String _title = 'Forts in Maharashtra';
      MyApp({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
      final String title;
      @override
      _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        new FirebaseNotifications().setUpFirebase();
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.deepOrange),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(
                  AppLocalizations.of(context).apptitle, //Translates the text
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23.0),
                ),
                backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
                actions: [
                  Icon(Icons.language, size: 28),
                  LanguagePick(),
                  const SizedBox(width: 12),
                ],
              ),
              body: MyBottomNavigationBar()),
        );
      }
    }
    
    class MyBottomNavigationBar extends StatefulWidget {
 
    
    class _MyBottomNavigationBarState extends State<MyBottomNavigationBar> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            body: _children[_currentindex],
            bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
              type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
              selectedItemColor: Colors.deepOrange,
              onTap: onTappedBar,
              currentIndex: _currentindex,
              items: [
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.explore),
                    label: AppLocalizations.of(context).exploreforts), //Giving error here
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(MdiIcons.waves), label: 'Sea Forts'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.terrain), label: 'Attractions'),
                BottomNavigationBarItem(
                    icon: Icon(Icons.location_city), label: 'City Forts'),
              ],
            ));
      }
    }`
```

I am trying to use the Localization feature in my application. I am able to change the AppBar title to another language but I am unable to change the language on the BottomNavigationBar.  I am having trouble changing the language in BottomNavigationBar. The App language is changed on the AppBar but I am facing issues while using the same in the BottomNavigationBar. I have added comments where required.

Comment: Add your code to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are defining two MaterialApp. You only need to define one in the main and render it in the entire app, remove the MaterialApp from the _MyAppState class